# junit no webapplication context found: no ContextLoad Listener registered?

Tags: java, junit4, spring-junit

I am trying to write test cases for my structs application in which some of configurations in springs based xml files.
i moved all my applicationContext files into src/test/resources class path but when i run my test class(RunAs-> Junit Test), it throws below error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:90)
    at com.cisco.attrui.test.BundleSearchActionTest.getPidBTSplitPctSearchTest(BundleSearchActionTest.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like similar problem as in other post I recently answered here:
[JUnit 4.12: testing util classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46278426/junit-4-12-testing-util-classes/46279039#46279039)

Moving xml configs to classpath is not enough. You need to tell Spring which ones to use and you need to use Spring test runner in the first place.

Like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/integrationContextTest.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TdkSMSSenderTest  {
}
```

Comment: @ContextConfiguration(locations ={"classpath:applicationContexttest-service.xml","classpath:applicationContexttest-dao.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
i have my xml files in classpath and it's getting called .. but i guess in my Web.xml file  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> it's not invoked during test- phase, please let me know how it can be called/configured for test executions

Comment: Aha - in my tests web.xml does not matter during tests - contexts areloaded by Spring test support classes, no ServletContextListener needed. I load context, get tested bean, call its method, assert. I see there is this @WebAppConfiguration https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html ,whch involves loading web app contexts, but I don't have any experience in using it.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in src/test/resources, you can add the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation to your test class to fetch as many files as required by providing them in an array follows:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:one-file.xml","classpath:another-file.xml", "classpath:and-another-file.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Comment: Yes i use the above pattern and xml files are getting called.. but it say's 
no ContextLoaderListener registered ... which is  the listener class mentioned in Web.xml file AS below, i think it's getting failed over here invoking  during test- pahse <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
     </listener>